# Where to post questions that might not fit serverfault?

Tags: support

I have a issue with high system cpu usage with qemu but because i use a panel (virtualizor) that (probably?) doesn't fit on sf. I mainly just dont want to get downvoted into oblivion because "it doesnt fit 100%" Is it safe to post or should i be looking somewhere else for support (virtualizor support already gave up on it as it "wasnt their software causing the issue")

Comment: from my experience having one bad question leads to a ton of downvotes which leads to you not being able to lose all features. That is why i generally dont like using Stackoverflow but as i was denied support in most other placed i thought i'd give it a chance.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a panel, do you have a provider, or did you set it up yourself? Talk to your provider's support staff.

Alternatively, there are some coding/IT fora around. Reddit might be a good place to look.

Comment: I used virtualizor but they were not able to help that well as its 'not their software" and QEMU support is also very inactive. I can try reddit but as it looks like a quite advanced issue i doubt that will help much